# Git avoid pushing new branches to remote through local config

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am familiar with **.git/config** file in the repository (basic understanding) and I would like with some changes in this configuration file to **avoid that a new branch in the remote is created**. Is this possible?

I have seen a few nice approaches from the server side, but since we are using Bitbucket I believe it's not possible to add a bash hook to the repository, which would easily solve the problem. I have also seen some of the plugins and none seem to do it (or could not find it).

I've Spent some time reading and "trying" to understand better the config file format which has many options, hoping that one option will allow me to do this, but no success so far.

Bottom line:

- Most important is that no new branch except the existing ones are created in the remote
- If this parameter also avoids the creation of a new branch locally even better.
- I have no problem with local permissions. I understand that a user can edit the config file himself and just create the remote brannch, but this is not a security issue, it´s just a workflow improvement for our release process.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: I honestly don’t know what you mean. What changes are you making which creates a branch in a remote repo?

Comment: It is a random shot, as it is not based on personal experience, but can Branch Permission model in Bitbucket help you here by any chance? :) https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/branch-permissions-385912271.html?_ga=2.176805414.2039171975.1570293044-1433259838.1570293044

Comment: @evolutionxbox this will create a new branch in the remote: `git checkout -b new_branch` and then `git push --set-upstream origin new_branch` I would like to avoid that this happens. I want to keep only a master branch in this repository.

Comment: @sbat Thanks for the hint. I had already checked this possibility, but I don´t see how I can avoid the creation of a new branch. I want only one branch in the repository: master. No others. With the Bitbucket branch permissions you can do other complex branch related permissions, but you cannot avoid that a new branch is created, at least I have not managed to do that.

Comment: What about a git server hook? Like a post receive? https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks#server-side-hooks

Comment: Thanks @evolutionxbox in our Bitbucket server version (6.5.1) this setup option for server side Hooks is no longer available. This is the latest [hook configuration documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/hooks-merge-checks-guide/?utm_source=%2Fbitbucket%2Fserver%2Fdocs%2Flatest%2Fhow-tos%2Fhooks-merge-checks-guide.html&utm_medium=301) and you either use an existing hook plugin or you need to use the Atlassian SDK which is out of our scope